# Problema con captura de información retornada por hilos en python

Tags: python-3.x, hilos

Cordial saludo,
Actualmente estoy creando un programa para hacer comparaciones entre dos listas de nombres; quiero que cada hilo que cree me compare la lista 1 con una parte de la lista dos; ejemplo lista 1 vs de a 3 posiciones de la lista 2.
Estoy creando hilos mediante el uso de Pool de Threads de la siguiente manera:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)
```

Y para lanzar el hilo hago lo siguiente

```
 for i in range(8):
    executor.submit(cruce,limite_inferior,limite_superior,lista1,lista2)
```

Donde cruce es una función que me compara las posiciones de la lista uno con las posiciones de la lista dos teniendo en cuenta los limites que le pase como parámetro, la función me retorna una lista con los nombres que se repiten. El problema de esto es que no se como capturar la información que me retornan los hilos y concatenar todas las listas que cada hilo me retorna para obtener solo una lista con los nombres repetidos lo intente de la siguiente manera:

```
 for i in range(8):
    nombres_repetidos = executor.submit(cruce,limite_inferior,limite_superior,lista1,lista2)
```

Pero me aparece el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Future object
```

Answer (score 2):

Como ya has observado, `ThreadPoolExecutor` te devuelve un [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#future-object). Este tipo de objetos representan (como deducimos por el nombre) un valor futuro.

Piensa que al lanzar tus hilos, estos van *desacoplados* de tu hilo principal, y tendrán su propio tiempo de ejecución. Tardarán mas o menos tiempo, y el orden en el que se ejecutan es totalmente desconocido y depende del Sistema Operativo. No necesariamente el primero que lanzaste será el primero en terminar.

Pero, mientras esos hilos están o no ejecutándose, tu hilo principal continua a su ritmo. Es muy probable que tu bucle termine antes de que terminen todos los hijos. Y es muy muy problame que la ejecución de la instrucción

```
executor.submit(cruce,limite_inferior,limite_superior,lista1,lista2)
```

sea mucho más rápida que la ejecución del hilo en sí.

Entonces, se necesita una manera de volver a *acoplar* tu hilo principal con los hilos creados. Y eso es un `Future`.

Tienes varias formas de acceder a los resultados reales. Una de las mas cómodas es el método `Future#result( )`, que, si es necesario, **detiene** tu hilo principal hasta que el hilo hijo asociado haya terminado. Observa que digo `si es necesario`. Si el hilo en cuestión ya terminó, no hay necesidad de esperar, y el resultado lo obtenemos de inmediato.

Por lo tanto, la forma correcta es:

1. Lanzar todos los hilos.
2. Esperar por los resultados.

En código:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)
futures = [ ]
results = [ ]

for i in range(8):
  futures.append(executor.submit(cruce,limite_inferior,limite_superior,lista1,lista2))

for i in futures:
  results.append(i.result( ))
```

¿ Y que pasa si tus funciones devuelve más de 1 resultado ? Por desgracia, `Future#result( )` **solo devuelve 1 valor**, así que tendrás que modificarlas para que se ajusten a ello. No debería haber mayor problema, puedes devolver una lista de cosas, o usar una clase *a medida* para tal fin.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, como se lograria hacer esto pero si la funcion retorna mas de una lista? intente seguir los pasos del comentario pero aun me persiste el error. Hice lo siguiente `a,b=executor.submit(cruce,limite_inferior,limite_superior,lista1,lista2) ` y luego `A_futures.append(a)    B_futures.append(b)` para finalmente `for i in A_furures: results_A_futures.append(i.result())` y otro for para B, cual seria la forma correcta?

Comment: @AlexanderBermúdezCastañeda. Puedes retornar una lista de listas.